# Keep calling 3rd party until it returns expected response with Hystrix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am looking for a way to call 3rd party service from my code(Spring Boot app), and in case it is unresponsive, I would like to repeat the call x amount of times and then provide a default fallback. I found an example pseudocode that would probably work in my case with Hystrix

```
public class ExampleClass {

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "example_Fallback")
    public String myMethod() {

        // third party service
        String response = httpClient.execute();

        return "OK";
    }

    private String example_Fallback() {

        return "ERROR HAPPENED";
    }
}
```

However, I would also like to repeat the call to same third-party service x amount of times if it returns a normal response that's unexpected.(treat that specific response as if the third party is unresponsive). The reason for that is because, third party might not be able to serve the request and I can only check that in the response. Could someone point me in the right direction  or provide an example how this could be solved with Hystrix ?

Answer (score 0):

> ...I would like to repeat the call x amount of times and then provide
>   a default fallback.

Configuring [`circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold`](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#circuitbreakerrequestvolumethreshold) may help here. Take a look at the other [Hystrix properties](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#circuitbreakerrequestvolumethreshold) as well.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "example_Fallback", commandProperties = {
   @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "5"),
   @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "2000")
   }
)
public String myMethod() {
  ...
}
```

Notice that `circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold` (quote) "...sets the minimum number of requests in a rolling window that will trip the circuit". The rolling window duration - `metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds` - defaults to 10 seconds.

There's also the [`@Retryable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html) annotation in Spring.